# Remote Notification will present not working ios 15.5

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, foreground, unusernotificationcenter

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
    
    completionHandler([.sound,.banner,.badge])
}
```

In application did-finish

```
 UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
```

I see the notification when the app in the background but do not see it in the foreground.

Comment: Does your delegate get called on the latest release, iOS 15.6? I tried to reproduce your issue on iPadOS 15.6 but couldn't. My delegate does keep getting `willPresent` calls reliably, also when the app is in the foreground. Are you sure that your delegate is set, and that the delegate does get called on previous versions, like iOS 15.4.1? Are you using `SwiftUI.App` or `@UIApplicationMain`?

Comment: I haven't updated my phone to ios 15.6 i'm still running 15.5. I only get it reliably in the background and not in the foreground. Did receive Remote-notification    is called both in foreground and background, so the app is receiving the payload its just not showing the banner in the foreground. I am using UIApplicationMain and i'm certain the delegate is set.